# What will be RTMP URL for nginx

Tags: nginx, stream, rtmp

Can you please tell me what will be me stream URL if I am using following code in nginx.conf

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            pull rtmp://THIS_IS_SOME_STREAM live=1;

            hls on;
            hls_path /mnt/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work:
`rtmp://My_Server_Ip/show`

**EDIT**

```
rtmp {  
        server {  
                listen 1935;  
                chunk_size 4000;  
                application live2 {  
                        live on;  
                        pull rtmp://Stream_IP app=vod/demo.mp4  name=okstr live=1;  
                }  
        }  
}
```

AND

```
rtmp {  
        server {  
                listen 1935;  
                chunk_size 4000;  
                application live2 {  
                        live on;  
                        pull rtmp://Stream_IP/vod/demo.mp4  name=okstr live=1;  
                }  
        }  
}
```

Then I tried following URL in VLC but it didn't any show video nor any error.

`http://My_IP/live2/okstr`

Answer (score 1):

The general format is: `[rtmp://]host[:port][/app[/playpath]]`

In the case of `pull` if the *playpath* is empty it uses the current stream name.

You either didn't set the play path, the pull doesn't work or the firewall blocks RTMP. Check the logs.

Comment: You are right about "play" path which I didn't define. I tried a couple of settings but the stream is not playing. It doesn't show any error in VLC, it just doesn't play. I feel like I am THIS close to solving this issue so please have a look at it.

I have updated new code above.

Comment: Hi aergistal pls answer my this qn if possible
Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117072/right-or-practical-way-to-ingest-multiple-rtmp-streams-and-push-hls-to-many-view

Answer (score 0):

The second config with

```
pull rtmp://Stream_IP/vod/demo.mp4  name=okstr live=1;
```

is correct one. Or you can edit this way:

```
pull rtmp://Stream_IP app=vod playPath=demo.mp4 name=okstr live=1;
```

Play url for it would be rtmp://yourserverip/live2/okstr.
But I have similar issue with pull setup not working in weird way. It does serve first 4 connects but does not all following them. Just disconnects right after play stream rtmp command. ffplay does say "invalid data found while processing input".
I had to use additional ffmpeg instance for relay, running in separate or in exec_static. This push scheme is ok.
Also make sure that worker_processes is 1; and rtmp_auto_push is off or commented; as multiworker config has an issues.